# Upload image file using onclick function and ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to upload image file using `onclick` function and ajax is it possible ? I search about on how to upload image but only i can see is via click function. but I have a reason for this that's why i used onclick function. controller is always null value

```xml
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ImagePath, new { @class = "form-label" })
        <input type="file" name="file" id="files" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="saveImage()"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> &nbsp;Submit Image</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery and ajax

```js
function saveImage() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#files')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("index", "payable")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

My controller

```cs
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    fileName = fileName + extension;
    var ImagePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;
    fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(fileName);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Your Ajax call is sending the file by POST while that Index method is GET (the default). You need `[HttpPost]` attribute and please don't call it Index, choose proper name.

Comment: @derloopkat ill try to add [httppost] but still the same my file parameter is null.

Comment: in your ajax, set these to false: `contentType: false, processData: false,`

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
var ufiles = $("#fileInput")[0].files;
if (ufiles.length > 0) {
  if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
    var fileData = new FormData();
    //handling multiple files or single file
    for (var x = 0; x < ufiles.length; x++) {
      fileData.append(ufiles[x].name, ufiles[x]);
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "yourUrl",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: fileData,
      success: function (result) {
        //do something with result
      },
    });
  } else {
    alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!"); //bootbox dependency
  }
}
```

And on server side:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = HttpContext.Request.Files[0];//this can be put under foreach for multiple files

            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + extension;
            var ImagePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(fileName);
            //now cause we are hadnling ajax
            return Json(fileName,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```